# document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag

Tags: w3c-validation

I am getting a w3c validation error here as

```
    The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've forgotten to close a previous element.

    One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "<p>" or "<table>") inside an inline element (such as "<a>", "<span>", or "<font>").
```

This is my source code

```
<ul class="link">
    <li><a href="" class="selected"><span>1<div class="clr">&nbsp;</div><label>Vul Postcode in </label></span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span>2<div class="clr">&nbsp;</div><label>Restaurants </label></span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span>3<div class="clr">&nbsp;</div><label>Menukaart</label></span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span>4<div class="clr">&nbsp;</div><label>Afrekenen</label></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Please help me to find out the issue,

Thanks

Pallavi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a block element (`div`) inside of an inline element (`span`). This is not allowed.

- Solution 1: Change `span` to `div`:

  ```
  <a href=""><div>2<div class="clr">&nbsp;</div><span class="label">Restaurants </span></div></a>
  ```

  (You have to use HTML5 (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), otherwise block elements wouldn’t be allowed inside of `a` elements.)
- Solution 2: Change `div` to `span`:

  ```
  <a href=""><span>2<span class="clr">&nbsp;</span><span class="label">Restaurants </span></span></a>
  ```

Note that you can’t have `label` inside of an `a` element (I changed the `label` to `span` here). Use the `label` element only when you have a `form`.

Comment: I have changed the code with <li><a href=""><div class="dspan">2<div class="clr">&nbsp;</div><label>Restaurants </label></div></a></li>
     <li><a href=""><div class="dspan">3<div class="clr">&nbsp;</div><label>Menukaart</label></div></a></li>
     <li><a href=""><div class="dspan">4<div class="clr">&nbsp;</div><label>Afrekenen</label></div></a></li>, but same result

Comment: @Pinky: I updated my answer. Your code should be correct regarding the use of `div` (if you use HTML5!). However, the `label` is not allowed there (different error).